# Compile error using C# automatically implemented properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

A C# Noob, I am trying to use SharpDevelop utility to convert my VB.NET application a C#.

I am noticing that my automatically implemented properties are generating a lot of errors. For example, take the following property:

public SqlDateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

Whenever I try to access the implied underlying module level variable, _DateOfBirth, I get the error.

Error   699 The name '_DateOfBirth' does not exist in the current context   D:\Users\Chad\Desktop\BESI CSharp\BESI\BESI.BusinessObjects.ConvertedToC#\ChinaVisa.cs  240 13  Besi.BusinessObjects.Converted

I could expand the properties declarations out to full-fledged properties, but this should n't be necessary and I'd like to understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot access the compiler-created backing variable - you must use the property.  The compiler-generated backing field is specifically named in such a way to prevent you from accessing it (it is not named `_DateOfBirth`, it is named something like `<DateOfBirth>k__BackingField`).

Access the property directly - if you need to manipulate the backing field directly then don't use an automatically implemented property.

Just a side note - it doesn't matter what the property name is (it is an implementation detail and could change on different versions of the compiler or with different compiler implementations altogether).  The field is given an identifier that is specifically designed to meet the naming restrictions of the CLR but fail the naming restrictions of C# making it impossible to ever write straight C# code that accesses that variable directly.

Also remember that automatically implemented properties are *not* public fields.  They are a shorthand that the compiler expands for you (sort of like a macro).

So this class:

```
class Bar
{
    public object Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Gets expanded to this:

```
class Bar
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private object <Foo>k__BackingField;

    public object Foo
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return this.<Foo>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            this.<Foo>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

It is still a full property - you are simply allowing the compiler to write the getters and setters for you.

Comment: Hmm. You can do this in Vb.NET. if you can't do this in C#, how is an implicit property any different than a Public variable?

Comment: @Chad: Properties are accessed differently than fields, so if you use automatic properties and decide to put some more code in the accessors later, you won't break assemblies referencing your code. If you change a field to a property, then assemblies referencing your assembly will break if you don't recompile them.

Comment: I'll vote your answer the correct one as soon as the timer allows, but one more question: As far as I can tell, at least in VB.NET, accessing a property in a class is the same as accessing a public variable. How are they different?

Comment: @Chad - Great question!  When you access a public field and a public property you do use the same syntax (in both languages) but the metadata emitted by the compiler for these members is very different.  This means that code calling your class may be using reflection (for example) to work with your class and since the metadata for properties and field differ you will break this client's code if you switch the member from a field to a property.

Comment: Excellent answer. Very clear explanation of what happens underneath that setters and getters.

Answer (score 1):

If you use automatically generated properties, you cannot rely on the compiler picking any specific name for the backing field. That's entirely compiler-specific, and even if you could access those fields, your code might still break if you use another compiler.